# 'Path must be a string' error after execute a cucumber feature

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, cucumber

I'm working in the implementation of cucumber with protractor I already have the conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  specs: './features/login.feature',

  onPrepare: function(){
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()
    browser.get('http:www.google.com')
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  },

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/steps/my_steps.js',
  }
};
```

This is my step file that just contain a console.log:

```
module.exports = function(){
  this.Given(/Display something/, function () {
    console.log('Hi');
  });
}
```

and this is the feature:

```
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor

  Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
    Given Display something
```

but every time that I execute with the command

```
protractor conf.js
```

i'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection VError: a handler errored, process exiting: PrettyFormatter::handleFeaturesResult: Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

i'm not sure if I have problems in the conf.js or the command is not the right to execute.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

in the `conf.js` in the `cucumberOpts:` I add this:

```
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/steps/my_steps.js',
    format: 'pretty',
    tags:'false'
  }
```

So for me is working now I hope this is a solution for you guys.